Is there a korean letter for the "Uh" in "Umbrella"? Alternatively worded, what is the hangul glyph for the open-mid back unrounded vowel?
Many English words contain the "uh" sound found in the word "umbrella".
That is, many English words contain the open-mid back unrounded vowel.
Other examples of English words containing the open-mid back unrounded vowel are shown below...



ENGLISHSPELLING  
INTERNATIONALPHONETICALPHABET
AN AMERICANPHONETICNOTATIONFORYOUNGCHILDREN




Umbrella
/ʌmbɹɛlə/
UhMBREhLUh


Up
/ʌp/
UhP


Done
/dʌn/
DUhN


America
/ʌmɛɹ.ɪ.kʌ/
UhMEhRIhKUh



What letter in the Korean alphabet (if any) is used for the English Uh sound?

It would be the vowel ㅓ.  An uh-like sound made by the English vowel "u" or "o" is transliterated as ㅓ, so 엄브렐러 (umbrella), 업 (up), 던 (done) and so on.
"America" is spelled 아메리카 though.  Unstressed "a" making the "uh" sound in English is transliterated as ㅏ rather than ㅓ, This is to follow the general rule of equating "a" with ㅏ (e.g. atom = 아톰, Abraham = 아브라함), because that is the sound it will take on in most languages except English.
Other such examples are Samoa (사모아) and Alhambra (알함브라 or 알람브라).
